# Trade mark and copyright are changed to unicodes in database of wordpress

Tags: php, database, wordpress, unicode

I'm having some issues regarding the WordPress database as it saves the product/post titles as Unicode if it has some trademark or copyright characters. I tried to change the **Config.php** file and commented on this code
`define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');`
`define('DB_COLLATE', '');`
but I think it didn't work. Any suggestions on how can I change it?
***On database TM looks like `product Test &#x2122; &#x2122; &#x2122;`***

Comment: Do you have access to the database? and if so, what collation is the field in question?

Comment: Changing in config.php is too late. The database already have a defined charset. Either you modify it in database, or find a way to transcode. Personally I think `utf8mb4` is the correct way, so do not remove it. remember: web is now UTF-8 (so unicode). In any case you are completely off-path on the reason. In database you have entities (see them as escape sequences) and they are pure ASCII. The roblem (which I do not understand from your question) should be corrected in other places (if it is a real problem)

Comment: That doesn't look like the db that is encoding it. That's HTML encoding for special characters, so most likely WP is encoding for displaying as HTML.

Comment: Yeah but klaviyo uses a plugin to integrate with woocom and takes the data there so we modify the plugin and run the integration(historic data import) again and should work for on-site previews too. @GarrGodfrey

Answer (score 0):

Inside the plugin file look for wck-cart-rebuild look for
`'Name' => $product->get_name(),`
and replace it to
`'Name' => html_entity_decode($product->get_name()),`

Note: you may need to reimport historical data on the website from dashboard/integration/woocom